# Can't run synaptic on an Xfce Ubuntu system

Tags: xfce, authentication, synaptic

So I installed Ubuntu with Xfce (using crouton) and tried to run synaptic and ran into the following:

```
$ synaptic-pkexec 
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR com.ubuntu.pkexec.synaptic ===
Authentication is required to run the Synaptic Package Manager
Authenticating as: *redacted*
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: error response to PolicyKit daemon: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: No session for cookie
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Error executing command as another user: Not authorized

This incident has been reported.
```

I made my user a root user (I can install and uninstall things using `apt-get`). What is wrong?

Comment: "I made my user a root user" How?

Comment: @muru I mean gave root privileges (I.e. can use sudo).

Comment: "How" != "What"

Comment: @muru Crouton did it automatically.

Answer (score 5):

Use it with `sudo`

```
sudo synaptic-pkexec
```

Worked for me when trying to use in a fresh install of Xfce4 on Debian; should work for Ubuntu as well.

Additionally, when I did the fresh install, I could not launch synaptic graphically (through GUI). A fix to this is installing the following packages:

```
sudo apt install synaptic apt-xapian-index policykit-1-gnome
```

`policykit-1-gnome` makes the GUI auth dialog for synaptic possible, without which synaptic will run, but it won't show anything on the GUI.

`apt-xapian-index` is basically for maintaining the package indexes.

Comment: On XFCE with Debian 11, `apt install policykit-1 policykit-1-gnome` fixed this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, Polkit priviliges on Ubuntu are granted to the admin user using the `sudo` group. Looks like whatever crouton does to give you `sudo` privileges did not add you to the `sudo` group.

Do:

```
sudo adduser $USER sudo
```

And re-login. Check that you're in the `sudo` group now using the `groups` or `id` command.

Comment: I did that and it said "The user 'redacted' is already a member of 'sudo'."

Comment: @PyRulez In that case, it's probably this bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=842184

Comment: It also occurs with the lubuntu-software-center